# pdfMake Link Not Showing Correctly From Inside Table Cell

Tags: pdfmake

I'm using pdfMake on Angular to create a pdf file that has a table. One of the columns is supposed to have a link. The link insertion only appears to be working outside of the table. Inside the table it shows as [Object object]

```
          table: {
            body: [[ 'Name', 'Description', 'Details', 'Link' ]]
                .concat(this.elements.map((element, i) => ['' + element.name, '' + element.description, '' + element.details, '' + { text: 'Visit site', link: 'http://www.google.com' }]))
          },
        },
```

Thank you for taking the time to consider this issue

A link inside a table